# Android Wear to Handset Communication

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I'm in the middle of creating an application for Wear that has a phone companion app to do some of the heavier processes and make API calls.

So far in regards to communication between the two devices, I have been following this tutorial - http://android-wear-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html

This has left me with the phone being able to communicate with the watch, but now I'm wondering how I replicate it working the other way.

The current code I have on the Wear app is like this (a seperate listener class is also present on the phone and watch):

```
public void sendTestMessage(View view)
{
    String WEARABLE_DATA_PATH = "/wearable_data";
    DataMap dataMap = new DataMap();
    dataMap.putString("WATCH2PHONE TEST MESSAGE EVENT!", "1");
    new SendToDataLayerThread(WEARABLE_DATA_PATH, dataMap).start();
}

class SendToDataLayerThread extends Thread
{
    String path;
    DataMap dataMap;

    SendToDataLayerThread(String p, DataMap data)
    {
        path = p;
        dataMap = data;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        PutDataMapRequest putDMR = PutDataMapRequest.create(path);
        putDMR.getDataMap().putAll(dataMap);
        PutDataRequest request = putDMR.asPutDataRequest();
        DataApi.DataItemResult result = Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleClient, request).await();

        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess())
        {
            Log.v("myTag", "DataMap: " + dataMap + " sent successfully to data layer ");
        }

        else
        {
            Log.v("myTag", "ERROR: failed to send DataMap to data layer");
        }
    }
}
```

Listener Class (for watch, the phone version is identical):

```
public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents)
    {
        DataMap dataMap;
        for (DataEvent event : dataEvents)
        {
            Log.v("myTag", "DataMap received on device: " + DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem()).getDataMap());
        }
    }
}
```

So sending the test message sends the messages to the layer and they send, but are received by the watch's listener service.

I'm assuming the "String WEARABLE_DATA_PATH = "/wearable_data";" is what's causing it to end up being received by the watch but I'm unsure what to change it to in order to get it to send properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Data API works the same in both directions. The specific architecture to use on the handheld depends on your app's structure, but there is a good overview of the options in the documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html#Listen.

That page also discusses using a path to filter the data events received. Again, this depends on your architecture, but it might be reasonable to use paths like `"/data_from_handheld"` and `"/data_from_wearable"` to differentiate the DataItems going in the different directions. Or you can use the same path, and then the data events will appear on all connected devices - which may or may not be what you want.

One other common "gotcha": Data API events only fire when the data has **actually** changed. This is an efficient way for the API to handle real-world communications, but can make development difficult. To force it, simply include an item that is always different, such as:

```
dataMap.putLong("timestamp", System.nanoTime());
```

...but be sure to take that out before deploying the app!